# Google bigquery to look at event triggered by same person this month and in the past

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics

I am tracking events such as this:

```
event_name = 'select_content'
event_param.key = 'content_id'
event_param.value.string_value = 'Under25'
```

I can see how many people selected each value by day which is great. However I would now like to show how many people for a given date and chose an option have previously chosen a different option.

Struggling to do the comparison of in effect new and returning users.